# Update an ListView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have an View which contains an List-View and an Button. When the Button is pressed there will be added an new Item to an array. The List View displays all of the items in this array. But If I press the button, the List-View dont display the changes in the array.

Here is my Code:

```
import SwiftUI

var myArray = ["Harald", "Jürgen", "Günter"]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            List(myArray, id: \.self) {
                Name in
                Text(Name)
            }
            Button(action: {
                myArray.append("Harald")
                print(myArray)
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My question is now how I can do it, that my List View will display new Items / changes as well.
Thanks, Boothosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myArray needs to be an @State and it needs to be inside the ContentView.
I recommend you to read and watch some SwiftUI tutorials.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myArray = ["Harald", "Jürgen", "Günter"]
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            List(myArray, id: \.self) {
                Name in
                Text(Name)
            }
            Button(action: {
                myArray.append("Harald")
                print(myArray)
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
    }
}
```